# Emacs for ipython

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I am using Emacs Version 24.3 on mac. and python is '2.7.6', ipython is '1.2.1'.

But when I want to use ipython in emacs with code:

```
(require 'python)
(setq
  python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
  python-shell-interpreter-args ""
  python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
  python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
  python-shell-completion-setup-code
    "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
  python-shell-completion-module-string-code
    "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
  python-shell-completion-string-code
    "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

but when I press 'C-c C-z', it shows:

```
Run Python: nil
```

when I just press ENTER, error returned:

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory, nil
```

I also have tried:

```
Run Python: python
```

python (**not ipython**) interpreter shows up with error:

```
ImportError: No module named IPython.core.completerlib
```

How can I make it right to use Ipython interprter in emacs??? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [python-mode](https://launchpad.net/python-mode) there's a menu `PyShell -> ipython-dedicated`. I think that's simplest.

Comment: And I'm using emacs24.3, as I learned from web, in the version most people use python.el instead of python-mode.el, and it makes the ipython in emacs easier, but I don't know why mine doesn't work.

Comment: @acui145: well, just download the tar from the link I posted, and read `INSTALL` there. There's probably a simple solution for `python.el` as well. If You don't have other considerations You might try `python-mode.el`.

Comment: Cheers!!!I solved it!!!If I just change the 'python-shell-interpreter' into  'PATH/TO/IPYTHON', it works. This has been puzzling me for 2 months!!! THANK YOU!!!But I still do not understand why mine has to point out the directory of ipython?

Comment: Nice :) my trick with ipython is to enable `jedi` to have a nice completion system: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python#Jedi